# Is it possible to install software from hard disk?

Tags: installation

I have try to install a software name qubee wimax uh-235 driver from hard disk but I failed to install.

Why? I don't know. Also I don't know how to install software by using terminal.

Any one please help me? And I don't have any internet connection in Ubuntu so how can I update my software without internet connection and install other software? Please help me?

Comment: Plz provide the error that you see and the exact name of file including extension that you are running to install the driver.

Answer (score 4):

This all depends on what type of file you're trying to install. If it's a `.deb` just run

`sudo dpkg -i <deb-file>`

If it's is a `.tar.gz` or `.tar.bz2` it's most likely a source package. That means you will have to compile the application on your computer. This is usually described in a file in the archive called `INSTALL` or `README`. The most common way for these are

```
tar zxf <file.tar.gz> 'or' tar jxf <file.tar.bz2>
cd <dir_from_package>
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Of course installing source packages require that you have a compiler and the development libs required for the program you wish to install. Since you are on a ubuntu system I suggest you stick to installing `.deb` supported by the ubuntu version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Well the interesting and difficult part of the question is you don't have an Internet-connection. Which means you will have great deal of difficulty in downloading and installing a lot of drivers and updates. More than anything (as per my experience with Ubuntu or Linux) you have to have a net connection. And if you have a net-connection then many times you can easily install many utilities via 'synaptic manager'.

As you have asked about how to install softwares. In Linux different utilities have different ways of installation processes. On the top of it, many times you face some problems and have to resolve some issues, while installing a particular s/w. In which case you have to check forums for the solutions.

I suppose you are a novice to Linux (as I am). So try to put up the exact things that you do with your machine. If you are doing something in the terminal, then do post the command that you are giving or the error messages, in case you get any.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can install software from a hard disk through a gui called "APTonCD". But for that to work you'd need a system with the app on it in the first place. Worth checking out if I understand your question. You may have to create a CD first then ISO it onto a hard disk. I haven't used "APTonCD" so I'm not sure what options it gives you. It may allow you to save the apps onto a hard disk in the first place. Sorry I'm not too specific. Just giving you an option to explore.